# How can I stream live video to Wowza using HTML5 without Flash?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, wowza

I have found solutions online to capture screenshots, stream audio, and record and upload video but have been unable to find resources which demonstrate how to stream live video from the webcam. I have looked into WebRTC but can not figure out how to make that work with RTMP.

Comment: @oxguy3 I would like to do this in pure Javascript using `getUserMedia()`, not with third party software. Please remove your downvote as I do not believe you are familiar with Wowza.

Comment: Your question didn't really explain that you wanted to do something with JavaScript. Stack Overflow is for providing help with specific coding problems, and your question is a bit too broad.

Comment: @oxguy3 It seems broad but once you understand how Wowza works, it really isn't. All the methods to stream `getUserMedia()` (which was implied in my question because it's the only way to access the webcam using HTML5) are hacks that are not documented online and I was asking for information on one of them.

Comment: WebRTC is also JavaScript so I don't see how using JavaScript wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: Your question is asking "How do I perform this task?", but the types of questions we look for on Stack Overflow are more "Here's what I have done to try to perform this task. Why doesn't my solution work?"

Comment: @oxguy3 Yes, I am aware of that. The question is a _how_ because no amount of Google searches will return any examples of how to do anything similar. There is no documentation within W3C either. W3C documents a flow using an RTCPeerConnection, which is not supported by Wowza.

Comment: @DavidL.Rodgers I'm working with live streaming from web application, so have you found a solution only using javascript without any plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to encode to RTMP without the help of a browser plugin (i.e. Flash Player).  You can easily gain [access to your media devices](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/) with `getUserMedia`.  If you need to capture that stream remotely you will need to open a [PeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) to another peer (can be a server).  This remote peer CAN be a server if you need:

https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/webrtc.html
https://www.wowza.com/products/capabilities/webrtc-streaming-software